# Why is a DLL referenced/used by my project not found at runtime?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, sharepoint-2010, itext

I've added several iTextSharp DLLs to a Sharepoint 2010 project (deployed as a WebPart).

The Web Part compiles/runs fine (I can step through my WebPart project while interacting with the web part on a page on the Sharepoint site). That is, it runs fine until code is called that actually uses itextsharp.dll. Then, the page crashes, and I get (in the log file), "The system cannot find the file specified"

Do DLLs have to be deployed to a specific place for Sharepoint to find them, or...???

### UPDATE

Even after copying four itextsharp DLLs to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET (Windows Server 2008, .NET 3.5), I get the same err msg.

For the gory details from the log file:

```
03/30/2015 14:49:28.43  w3wp.exe (0x0968)                           0x1834  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6574839201' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    at XMLToPDF.XMLToPDFWebPart.XMLToPDFWebPart.ConvertFromXMLToPDF(List`1 listOfListItems)     at XMLToPDF.XMLToPDFWebPart.XMLToPDFWebPart.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ef8cece3-42f4-47d0-ab0a-ca2f0fff46e4
```

Comment: Pretty much the same rules for any ASP.NET site: the DLLs must be either installed in the GAC (if they are strongly signed) or installed in the app_bin folder. If iTextSharp depends on a native DLL it must also be installed. The files to install can be configured in the SharePoint artifact manifest settings under "advanced" IIRC.. but it's been awhile.

Comment: (That's not the GAC or local app bin.)

Comment: Okay; I googled where the GAC was for Windows Server 2008, and that's what I found. So where is the GAC?

Comment: Would it be this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies ?

Comment: Use [`gacutil` to install](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .. however, only use the GAC if required (usually related to full trust settings) and only use gacutil for testing (the solution should be a fully-automated deploy). It generally is better to deploy all the resources locally if possible and doing so adds less restrictions to the SP WSP package deployment.

Comment: I get, "gacutil is not recognized as an internal or external command, [etc.]"

Comment: (Solutions easily found with a search .. but you really ought not to be using `gacutil` manually, except for a toybox; the WSP package deploy can do this in a reliable manner .. it can also do the preferred *non-GAC* deploy of external resources.)

Comment: I tried Build > Package, and then Deploy, but still no joy.

Comment: WSP .. artifact .. manifest. See http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/ , eg. And later VS has this UI for the SP WSP manifest built-in. It would be beneficial to read up on how to package/deploy SharePoint solutions; it's been improved over the years but is roughly the same for self-hosted solutions. You can can see what files are really copied by opening up the WSP (it is just a zip file) and taking a peek at the contents.

Comment: The project has an "Assembly Deployment Target" property that is set to "GlobalAssemblyCache" One would think this would take care of things "automatically" (but it obviously doesn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [link provided by user2864740](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/) was key.

In a nutshell, this is what I did:

```
   2-clicked Package.package
   Selected the "Advanced" button
   Selected the "Add" > "Add Existing Assembly" button
   Verified "GlobalAssemblyCache" was selected
   Using the ellipsis button affiliated with the "Source Path" edit, added each needed DLL one at a time
   Saved Package.package
```

And: voila! Joy in Mudville, including a ticker-tape parade, a marching band featuring 76 trombones, and the whole nine yards (IOW, it worked).